# On right click(or contextClick) going out of iframe. How to perform correctly?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

In my app, i need to perform right click action on one element in a frame. I switched to that frame and the normal click action performs correctly, but for right click, the action is performing somewhere out side of the frame but not on the specified element.

To cross check I used following code:

```java
//switch to iframe
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2]/td/iframe")));
//click on element      
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//My xpath")).click();//correctly clicked on element

WebElement span=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//My xpath"));
//right click       
Actions right=new Actions(driver);
right.contextClick(span).build().perform();//not clicked on element. context click performed out side of frame
```

Comment: There's too many things that could have gone wrong. For one - you should switch to [`defaultContext()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#defaultContent%28%29) before you want to go from one `iframe` to a new one.

Comment: Thanks Slanec, plz check know and help me how to perform context click in this case

Comment: I just tried with IE8 and Selenium 2.24.1 and it works like expected, the element receives the right click successfully. Try to reduce your testing page to the state where it works so you could discover what's causing the problem.

Comment: Also, look at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/CHANGELOG, especially "Fixed calculation of coordinates for elements in frames/iframes where the element is scrolled out of view within the frame. Fixes issue #4800." in the newest 2.27.0 release. This could have been your issue!

Answer (score -1):

Try applying sleep between the element i.e.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//My xpath")).click();

Thread.Sleep(1000);

WebElement span=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//My xpath"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).